# Why is my brute-force MD5 hack not working?

Tags: c++, md5, brute-force

For class, I was given a password that was run through the md5 hash. I am told that it is a maximum of 6 characters, uppercase and digits only. I am to write a brute force algorithm to reveal the original password. I have been able to get my own hash values, run it through my program, and decode it, but it fails on the one my teacher gave us. I sourced  my md5 from a website and checked its results against others so I know that isn't the issue. Is there some error in my code, like I'm not covering all possible combinations, or is there most likely an error in the hash value given to me?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "md5.h"//File was sourced from http://www.zedwood.com/article/cpp-md5-function

using namespace std;

const int numPossibleChar = 36;
const string givenHash = "ad2ad129385e4b2ba3b477378bc1d9b6";
long count=0;//make sure I go through all combinations

const char * charOptions[numPossibleChar]={"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K",
                            "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V",
                            "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
                            "8", "9", "0"};



int main()
{   
    for( int i =0; i<numPossibleChar; i++)
    {
         string guess1 = charOptions[i];
        string guessHash = md5(guess1);
        if( md5(guess1)==givenHash)
        {
            cout <<"match, password is: "<< guess1<<endl;
            return 0;
        }
        cout<<guess1<<endl;
        count++;
        for (int j=0; j<numPossibleChar; j++)
        {
            string guess2=guess1+charOptions[j];
            if( md5(guess2)==givenHash)
            {
                cout <<"match, password is: "<< guess2<<endl;
                return 0;
            }
            count++;
            for(int k=0; k<numPossibleChar; k++)
            {
                string guess3=guess2+charOptions[k];
                if( md5(guess3)== givenHash)
                {
                    cout <<"match, password is: "<< guess3<<endl;
                    return 0;
                }
                count++;
                for(int l=0; l<numPossibleChar; l++)
                {
                    string guess4=guess3+charOptions[l];
                    if( md5(guess4)== givenHash)
                    {
                        cout <<"match, password is: "<< guess4<<endl;
                        return 0;
                    }
                    count++;
                    for(int m=0; m<numPossibleChar; m++)
                    {
                        string guess5=guess4+charOptions[m];
                        if( md5(guess4)==givenHash)
                        {
                            cout <<"match, password is: "<< guess5<<endl;
                            return 0;
                        }
                        count++;
                        for(int n=0; n<numPossibleChar; n++)
                        {
                            string guess6=guess5+charOptions[n];
                            if( md5(guess6)==givenHash)
                            {
                                cout <<"match, password is: "<< guess6<<endl;
                                return 0;
                            }
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Count "<<count<<endl;




    return 0;
}
```

And no, I don't actually have what the final value of count is. I intially has it as an int instead of a long, so after running 9 hours it overflowed. I wanted to check with you guys before I ran it again and got a new number.

Comment: Is the hash in the source code the one you were given? If not, which were you given?

Comment: Do you need to do that many string allocations? You could assemble the candidate strings in a char buffer to MD5 and compare the output as bytes without converting to a hex string to compare. (I don't know if that's significant w.r.t the MD5 computation time, but it seems superfluous.)

Comment: I would check that the basic algorithm works first, before adding the "md5" part (md5 is a fairly slow operation in the whole scheme of things). And use a short password, e.g. 3 letters, and make sure you can match find the match. For example "X9Z". For every extra character you add, it will take 36 times longer, so a couple of extra characters goes from minutes to several hours, making the problem "slow" to solve.

Comment: MD5 hash is not unique therefore your first positive may not be the original password. (several passwords can produce the same MD5 hash).

Comment: Whoever VTC as "needs problem statement" needs their eyes examined.

Comment: @Galik: True, but it's vanishingly unlikely that two 6-character strings would have the same md5sum. There are just over 2^31 possible passwords meeting the criteria; there are 2^128 possible md5sums. And I'll bet that it's been tested; if there were an md5sum collision for such short strings, it would be known. Relevant: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15873/what-is-the-md5-collision-with-the-smallest-input-values

Comment: I have found a md5 generator online in which I have input sample passwords, copied that into my program as the hash value to decrypt, and my code as-is, is able to decode it . I put a link to the md5 I used as a comment near the top of my code. I believe my professor used openssl to get his hash value. Is there anyway I can call opensll from within my code?

Comment: @KeithThompson I was thinking of the possibility that the professor had specifically selected a duplicate when crafting the assignment. It would explain why the algorithm works for the OPs test samples but not for the one provided by the professor.

Comment: @Galik: An interesting thought, but as I said there almost certainly aren't any duplicates that short.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Style issues aside,

```
                string guess4=guess3+charOptions[l];
                if( md5(guess4)== givenHash)
                {
                    cout <<"match, password is: "<< guess4<<endl;
                    return 0;
                }
                count++;
                for(int m=0; m<numPossibleChar; m++)
                {
                    string guess5=guess4+charOptions[m];
                    if( md5(guess4)==givenHash)
                    {
                        cout <<"match, password is: "<< guess5<<endl;
                        return 0;
                    }
```

I would venture a guess that you did not mean to check `md5(guess4)` twice.

Edit, to expand on this and style issues:
Obviously without checking `md5(guess5)`, one in six potential passwords would be missed.

There are easy ways around this type of bug by refactoring your code for better style. Of particular note, I suggest you read up on the [Arrow Anti-pattern](http://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/). You have a lot of code duplication (eg, conducting the nearly/exact same operations with different variables) which means you could easily refactor into either a recursive function or stacked (push/pop to heap style) loop and achieve easier-to-read (thus *generally* less-prone to errors) code.

If it took 9 hours for you to overflow your `count`, I would suggest you've got a bit of a performance problem (assuming you're running on relatively recent hardware). You could further expand on that to reduce the number of string allocations and deallocations by reusing your existing strings for each check. For example, `count` can be inferred strictly by adding `count=1+i+j+k+l+m+n`, so it wouldn't be necessary to increment it manually.

Comment: Oh my goodness, I think that is likely it. I sure hope so! Thank you. Ill run it again and then accept your answer.

Comment: So was that the issue?